# How to display a view on top on another?

Tags: android, android-xml

***What I have tried and how its visible now***:

[image]

***Code I have(Programatically i am able to give red area)***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewInbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="INBOX"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNewMsgId"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:letterSpacing="0.1"
                android:text="14"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:padding="2dp"/>

        </FrameLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

***What i am trying to achieve:Position of 14 is not to the perfected and top of inbox (How to achieve this)***

[image]

Comment: if you are looking for readymed solution https://github.com/AlexLiuSheng/BadgeView

Comment: Thats a good link .... Can I have a textView there instead of image ?

Comment: yes you can pass argument  `View`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add layout margin 10dp to the textviewinbox .
You can set that layout margin as per your view's requirements. May be it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have found this library which helps to your requirement

> compile 'com.allenliu.badgeview:library:1.1.1'

and you can customize according to your requirement like this

```
BadgeFactory.create(this)
.setTextColor(Color.White)
.setWidthAndHeight(25,25)
.setBadgeBackground(Color.Red)
.setTextSize(10)
.setBadgeGravity(Gravity.Right|Gravity.Top)
.setBadgeCount(20)
.setShape(BadgeView.SHAPE_CIRCLE)
.setSpace(10,10)
.bind(view);// you can pass View object that can be Textview ImageView Button etc...
```

Comment: Thank you  ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could rather use a constraint layout, would be much easier to achieve what you are trying to do.

Simplified code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inbox"
        android:text="inbox"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="14"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/inbox"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/inbox"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/inbox"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/inbox"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        //add some margins to push it over the "inbox" borders. />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```